# Not able to open the webpage through selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am new to selenium python and I am trying to scrape the data from a website. Below is the code, where I have taken all the necessary precautions to not get blocked.

```
from random import randrange
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#Function to generate random useragent.
def generate_user_agent():
    user_agents_file = open("user_agents.txt", "r")
    user_agents = user_agents_file.read().split("\n")
    i = randrange(len(user_agents))
    userAgent = user_agents[i]
    user_agents_file.close()
    return userAgent

#Function to generate random IP address.
def generate_ip_address():
    proxies_file = open("proxyscrape_premium_http_proxies.txt", "r")
    proxies = proxies_file.read().split("\n")
    i = randrange(len(proxies))
    proxy = proxies[i]
    proxies_file.close()
    return proxy

#Function to create and set chrome options.
def set_chrome_options():
    proxy = generate_ip_address()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    return options, proxy

#Function to create a webdriver object and set its properties.
def create_webdriver():
    options, proxy = set_chrome_options()
    userAgent = generate_user_agent()
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": proxy,
    "ftpProxy": proxy,
    "sslProxy": proxy,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",}
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts']=True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": userAgent})
    return driver

url = 'http://www.doctolib.de/impfung-covid-19-corona/berlin'
driver = create_webdriver()
driver.get(url)
```

The webpage is not opened via selenium web driver(but can be opened normally). Below is the screenshot of how the browser is opened when I run the code.

Please let me know If I am missing something. Any help would be highly appreciated

PS: I am using the premium proxies for IP rotation.

[Browser_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZBgS.png)

Comment: after quick look i think you have to check your proxy list.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar experience in the past where the website detects that selenium is being used, even after using several methods like IP rotation, User-Agent rotation or using proxies.

I would suggest you to use the [undetected_chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) library.

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

It's able to load the website without any problem.
The code snippet is given below:-

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
with driver:
    driver.get('http://www.doctolib.de/impfung-covid-19-corona/berlin')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue with Firefox on Linux. I just deleted the log file which was quite big for text file (4.8 mb) created by geckodriver and everything started to work fine again

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31474934)